# non-void return value in void function table view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function to retrieve data from parse and if it is nil then a table view will present one tableview cell but if the server has data then it will present a different table view cell. But I have to declare a return function and when I do I get an:

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function

error that I can't resolve. Here is the code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    if indexPath.row == 0 {




        // STEP 2. Find posts made by people appended to followArray
        let query = PFQuery(className: "CommercialUsers")
        query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! cell2
                cell.delegate = self
                return cell
                for object in objects! {
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! cell1
                    cell.delegate = self
                    return cell
                }

            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! cell1
            cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
```

And here is an image of the error
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRBz3.png)

Comment: You can't use `return` inside the `findObjectsInBackground` closure.

Comment: You're not returning a cell when `indexPath.row` is `0` because you are using an asynchronous function. I suggest you look up what asynchronous functions are and look at the examples of how to load data from Parse into a table view.

Comment: Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unexpected+non-void+return+value+in+void+function+%5Bswift%5D) before posting.

Comment: `findObjectsInBackground` expects a return type `Void`, but it's nested within a method that expects a return type of `UITableViewCell`. You're trying to return a `UITableViewCell` within an asynchronous block that doesn't expect a return type at all. This is also a very flawed design. As @EmilioPelaez mentioned, you should research asynchronous methods, and concurrency. I would suggest running this asynchronous Parse query, and when you receive a response, then handle reloading your table view using `DispatchQueue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

You are using a function, `findObjectsInBackground`, that takes a completion closure. The completion closure is another function inside your cellForRowAt function. That function holds onto (captures) the completion closure you pass in and doesn't call it until the background call is complete.

The block you pass in does not return a value. That's what

```
(objects, error) -> Void in
```

means. It says "this block takes 2 parameters, but does not return anything."

You can't return cell from inside that completion closure.

Instead, what you want to do is to call findObjectsInBackground, then, outside of it's block, finish configuring the cell and return it.

inside the completion closure for findObjectsInBackground, you should fetch the cell from the table view using `tableView.cell(at:)` and install your newly fetched data into the cell.

### EDIT:

I just noticed that you have code in your completion handler that ties to loop through your returned objects and create multiple cells. That won't work at all. you'll need to rethink your design.

The `cellForRow(at:)` function must fetch, configure and return a single cell. The async method that you're using won't complete until after your `cellForRow(at:)` function returns, so you'll need to return a cell without the data you are loading, and then install the data into the cell inside your completion handler.

Comment: There's a serious flaw with this. `cellForRow` expects a cell to be returned. Using `findObjectsInBackground` inside the `cellForRow` doesn't work because the data is needed "now", not "later".

Comment: @rmaddy, I guess I should have been clearer in my answer. I meant that you fully configure your cell in `cellForRow(at:)` and then either install placeholders or leave the fields blank that will be filled with the results of the async call. Then in the completion handler, you fetch the target cell and install the contents into it (or skip that step if the indexPath is no longer being displayed.